# Where to find ITaskSettings3 and IMaintenanceSettings definitions for VS2010 C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, windows-8, include

I'm trying to compile [this C sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (at the bottom of that page) using C++ console app project on VS2010 on a Windows 7 machine but it gives me undeclared identifier errors. I can't find definitions of `ITaskSettings3` and `IMaintenanceSettings`. You would think Microsoft will provide a code sample that compiles, hah :)

Any idea what includes am I missing?

**EDIT:** This is what I have in the properties for the project:

[image]

Comment: The _declarations_ are located in `<taskschd.h>`

Comment: Hmm. I just tried searching in it and `ITaskSettings3` is not there...

Comment: Since `ITaskSettings3` is available on Windows 8 and above only you probably need to update to a newer version of the Windows SDK.

Comment: I thought I installed it. Do I need to configure something in VS2010 to use it?

Comment: Open up the properties for your project and go into "Configuration Properties -> General". There's a setting called "Platform Toolkit" that lets you change the version of the SDK. There's a page on the [msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx) that has more information about SDK versions.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to select there? I posted a screenshot above.

Comment: I don't the SDK installed on my laptop but since `Windows7.1SDK` is the only one not listed on my side I would try that one first.

Comment: I thought it would be called 8.something, right? Where's it even located on the hard drive? I'm not sure what I installed...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile it with VS 2008 in C++ project, that allowed me to set include directories in the project properties for Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directorues. I included these:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared";"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\"

Obviously you need to download and install [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows 7, it will return: `Failed (Err: 0x80004002 -  This interface is not supported.)`

```
hr = pSettings->QueryInterface(IID_ITaskSettings3, (void**)&pSettings3);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"[-] Failed (Err: 0x%x - %s)\n", hr, _com_error(hr).ErrorMessage());
        goto CleanUp;
    }
```

Check your os version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/versionhelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindows7orgreater