# Can I install Windows 8 SDK on Windows 7 to compile C++ desktop app (no Metro stuff)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, sdk

I need to compile a C++ desktop app in VS2010 that uses definitions available only in Windows 8 SDK. I can't seem to find a definitive answer. Can I install it on my Windows 7 machine?

PS. I just tried installing [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx), but after the installer was done I can't seem to find that SDK on my computer.

**EDIT**: This is how I'm adding the include folder location:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The path is strangely `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0` on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. The question is how do I add it to my C++ project in VS2010?

Comment: All I get in the project properties is `v100`, `v90` and `Windows 7.1 SDK` I'm not sure, is it `v100`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, but it doesn't work. The `taskschd.h` with the correct definitions is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`. I'm not sure exactly what `um` stands for, but I added the main include to my project's properties (see screenshot above.) But the `taskschd.h` file that is used in the project still comes from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include` which doesn't include def's that I need for Windows 8. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/23/using-the-windows-8-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010-configuring-multiple-projects.aspx but the project script they provided doesn't work. I get a bunch or errors, starting with `wincred.h(91): error C2059: syntax error : 'return'` and the script that someone corrected in comments doesn't work either -- VS doesn't event accept it. There must be a way to install that Win 8 SDK on VS2010. I can't believe that they abandoned it like that?

Comment: I was able to achieve it by using VS 2008. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17139955/843732

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can .

you can visit this link for detailed info

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/23/using-the-windows-8-sdk-with-visual-studio-2010-configuring-multiple-projects.aspx